# Redirecting subdomain from an alias domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, subdomain, alias

So I have been searching the net along with this site regarding htaccess redirections, but have yet not managed to find the solution for myself (it may not even be possible).

So my scenario is this:
I have bought a cheap host, which comes with a subdomain, but also has the ability to add your own domain as an alias to it. Right now I can access the site using:
subdomain.hostprovider.com
and
mydomainasalias.com

What I wish to achieve here, is that I would be able to redirect a subdomain from the domain alias to a random page on a random site.

So 
subdomain.mydomainasalias.com
is basically
2ndsubdomain.subdomain.hostprovider.com

I have tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.mydomainasalias\.com$   [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://randomsite.com/asd  [L,R]
```

amongst some other things, to achieve this, but have yet not succeeded. Is it even possible?